# Which is right database tables structure for laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

Imagine I have USERS table, I have two types of users: client and service provider, each of them have their own table: CLIENTS and SERVICE_PROVIDERS. One user is client or service provider, not both of them, and I have many users. which table structure is correct? :

1)

```
USERS       ClIENTS         SERVICE_PROVIDERS
id           id             id
name         user_id        user_id
```

or

2)

```
USERS              CLIENTS         SERVICE_PROVIDERS
id                  id             id
name
userable_id
userable_type
```

second one is according to One To One (Polymorphic) Relationship.
so which one is more professional and correct?

Comment: First one assumes that 1 **user** can have many **clients** and many **providers**, so I would go with the second one.

Comment: The first one makes sense. I wouldn't go with the second one. Here are the third and fourth options: If your clients and service providers are functioning similarly; you can also use one table to store both kind of `users` with boolean or enumerable columns to identify type and check the type in logic. That would be much more understandable and manageable. You can also use two Eloquent classes `User` and `ServiceProvider` with one, single table `Users` (search for **single table inheritence**).